# Place of the adverb daily in the sentence

Tags: adverb-position

Is *daily* usually placed before or after the main verb?  It is not possible to effectively check it by searching the Web because *daily* is the adjective as well.

> Security for OEM storage is tied to the host system which verifies **daily** the drive and creates unique encryption keys to prevent theft.

Comment: This way is how I would typically expect to see it in US English: "Security for OEM storage is tied to the host system which verifies the drive daily and creates unique encryption keys to prevent theft." (Though my lead-in sentence does just the opposite with "typically"!)  I hope our better versed site pundits can explain *why* it's usually one way over the other. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting case. The conventional usage would be *verifies the drive daily*.

None of these are incorrect, but only the first is common:

> He had his brakes checked yearly
>
> He had his breaks yearly checked
>
> He yearly checked his brakes

Comment: Too subtle for me.  "Only the first is common" is understatement.  The google finds about 4K results for "yearly checked," and the first few pages are almost all non-textual uses or translations.  Over 34K results for "checked yearly."